# CSRF verification failed. Но токен передал

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Столкнулся с проблемой что не проверяет токен. Я  передал его внутрь формы, установил библиотеку и добавил ее в `INSTALLED_APPS`, но все равно выдает ошибку `CSRF verification failed`

`setting.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'page.apps.PageConfig',
    'payments.apps.PaymentsConfig',
    'crispy_forms'
]
```

`page/views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import DonatForm
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    form = DonatForm()

    return render(request, 'base.html', {'title': 'Ukraine Role Play', 'form': form})
```

`page/forms.py`

```
from django import forms


class DonatForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
    amount = forms.IntegerField(label='Amount')
```

`payments/view.py`

```
from page.forms import DonatForm


def send_payment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DonatForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            amount = form.cleaned_data['amount']

            liqpay = LiqPay(
                settings.LIQPAY_PUBLIC_KEY,
                settings.LIQPAY_PRIVATE_KEY
            )

            params = {
                'action': 'pay',
                'amount': f'{amount}',
                'order_id': f'{uuid4()}',
                'version': '3',
            }

            signature = liqpay.cnb_signature(params)
            data = liqpay.cnb_data(params)

            url = f'https://www.liqpay.ua/api/3/checkout?data={data}&signature={signature}'

            return redirect(url)
        else:
            return render(request, 'base.html', {'form': form})
```

`page/base.html`

```
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="modal-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"
                 style="background: rgb(4,32,44);color: rgb(255,255,255);border-radius: 0px;border-width: 0px;">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Донат</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="background: rgb(4,32,44);color: rgb(255,255,255);">
                <form action="{% url 'pay_view' %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form }}

{#                    <div class="row">#}
{#                        <div class="col-xl-10 offset-xl-0">#}
{#                            <label class="form-label">Email#}
{#                                {{ form.email }}#}
{#                            </label>#}
{#                            <label class="form-label">Сума#}
{#                                {{ form.amount }}#}
{#                            </label>#}
{#                        </div>#}
{#                    </div>#}
                    <div class="d-xl-flex justify-content-xl-end" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                        <button class="btn btn-light" type="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Закрити</button>
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Задонатити">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

И он подставляется
[image: И он подставляется]
На локалке такой проблемы нету

Также когда хочу зайти в админку такая же проблема. Есть какие-то способы это решить?

Comment: Ну если с админкой такая же ошибка, значит проблема видимо не в вашем коде. Куки нормально работают?

Comment: @andreymal, да в куки также заносится.

Comment: А в логах Django есть что-нибудь интересное? Обычно там пишется, почему конкретно verification оказался failed

Comment: @andreymal `Forbidden (Origin checking failed - https://rp.com does not match any trusted origins.): /payments/pay/` - вот и все

Comment: Но у меня на сервера такая система Nginx -> uwsgi -> django/python

Comment: А, это нужно прописать настройку [CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins) (она новая, сам вечно забываю про неё)

Comment: @andreymal, мдее, заработало, и давно такое нововведения, а то у меня еще один сайт лежит и там такой проблемы нету

Comment: (точнее, сама настройка старая, но в Django 4.0 изменили её формат и поведение)

Comment: @andreymal понял, спасибо за помощь